# Owl2Java Code generation issue

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I'm using the owl2java plugin to generate Java code from an Ontology file. But I'm always getting de same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ConversionException: Cannot convert node http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#bottomObjectProperty to TransitiveProperty
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.TransitivePropertyImpl$1.wrap(TransitivePropertyImpl.java:66)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:142)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:22)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.Polymorphic.asInternal(Polymorphic.java:54)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.viewAs(EnhNode.java:92)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhGraph.getNodeAs(EnhGraph.java:135)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl$SubjectNodeAs.map1(OntModelImpl.java:3040)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl$SubjectNodeAs.map1(OntModelImpl.java:3033)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.Map1Iterator.next(Map1Iterator.java:35)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.next(WrappedIterator.java:68)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.UniqueExtendedIterator.nextIfNew(UniqueExtendedIterator.java:61)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.UniqueExtendedIterator.hasNext(UniqueExtendedIterator.java:69)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.NiceIterator.asList(NiceIterator.java:185)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.NiceIterator.toList(NiceIterator.java:159)
at de.incunabulum.owl2java.core.generator.OwlReader.handleProperties(OwlReader.java:862)
at de.incunabulum.owl2java.core.generator.OwlReader.generateJModel(OwlReader.java:457)
at de.incunabulum.owl2java.core.JenaGenerator.generate(JenaGenerator.java:65)
at onto.main.main(main.java:99)
```

I have no idea about what I'm doing wrong. Any Ideas?

Thanks you a lot.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the ontology file, it looks like the file is wrong.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Absurd-Mind said: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the top line on your exception, and see `com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.TransitivePropertyImpl`.

Googling for that leads to [a version of the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.2/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/impl/TransitivePropertyImpl.java).  It may not be exactly the same version as you're using, but is probably close enough to be informative.  Reading the code leads to these questions:

- Does your Model have a profile?  It must.
- Does the profile support Transitivity? It must.
- Are you combining Transitive with something else that it's incompatible with?